# Consigo integrar meu banco SQLite com firebase?

Tags: firebase

Meu App está todo no SQLite, consigo integrar ja um App feito no Firebase? Se tem como, existe algum lugar explicando direitinho, pois tentei fazer e acabou dando erro de sync.

Comment: Meu problema é ao contrário, tenho tudo no firebase, e queria mandar para o SQLite. Alguém poderia ajudar ?